# How to Edit .aspx page and Save in asp.net on button click using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, writetofile, textwriter

I a list of .aspx page which is in DropdownList that are from Application Root Directory. I am showing the Whole .aspx Page content in RichTextBox for Editing. But, When i click on Save Button it shows Error:A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1="...xt" %>

Sample Code here:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="314px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width="771px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="BtnSaveContent" runat="server" onclick="BtnSaveContent_Click" 
        Text="Save Content" />

In .aspx.cs file:
private void GetFilesNames()
    {


        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("") + "/CopyText.aspx");
        TextBox1.Text = tr.ReadToEnd();
        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
    }


    protected void BtnSaveContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WritetoFile();
    }

    private void WritetoFile()
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("") + "/CopyText.aspx");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Page Header:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" validateRequest="false" CodeFile="CopyText.aspx.cs" Inherits="CopyText" %>

<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" validateRequest = false
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

i have also tried validateRequest="false" at page level and control level. but doesn't work!
Any Idea to resolve this error?
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you need `validateRequest = false`.

BUT if this is .Net 4.0 you also need to add `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to the httpRuntime configuration section of the `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Please show the header of your aspx page e.g. the `<%@ Page `

Comment: now it doesn't throw error but changes to file doesnt persist. after closing browser it shows me "Page is being updated outside source do you want to reload?" when i click "yes" it still remains the previous page contents..! any reason?

Comment: WHAT shows you that message? The Visual Studio? and on what file? the Web.Config?

Comment: Yes VS2010 v4.0 framework! Message: "The file is modified outside source editor do you want to reload?" with two options YES/NO,YESTOALL/NOTOALL! After closing the browser.

Comment: I meant, where is this message shown? Inside Visual Studio or inside your browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21329/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-blachshma)